# object to datetime conversion_ converting from mm/dd/yyyy object value type to date type (python, pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, type-conversion

All variables are object dtype. I'd like to convert the dtype from object to datetime.

```
    df = pd.DataFrame(
                    {"ID":['A','B','C','D','E'],
                     "date":['4/12/2017','4/27/2017','4/28/2017','4/29/2017','4/210/2017'],
                     })
```

What I've 3 different approaches. First,

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format="%m-%d-%Y")
```

This didn't work out, giving me value error saying "time data '4/12/2017' doesn't match format specified"

Second,

```
parse(exerciseCsv['mostRecentExerciseDate'], dayfirst=True)
```

Third,

```
[datetime.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%Y') for x in exerciseCsv['mostRecentExerciseDate']]
```

All of above didn't work out. This looks like a simple task, can anyone help me how to get this done and explain me why this isn't working?

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format="%m/%d/%Y")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need add parameter `errors='coerce'` if possible some bad data, which are converted to `NaT` (`NaN` for `datetime`):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors='coerce')
print (df)
  ID       date
0  A 2017-04-12
1  B 2017-04-27
2  C 2017-04-28
3  D 2017-04-29
4  E        NaT
```

If only typo in last value:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
                    {"ID":['A','B','C','D','E'],
                     "date":['4/12/2017','4/27/2017','4/28/2017','4/29/2017','4/21/2017'],
                     })

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
print (df)
  ID       date
0  A 2017-04-12
1  B 2017-04-27
2  C 2017-04-28
3  D 2017-04-29
4  E 2017-04-21
```

As mentioned [Stephen Rauch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43725014/object-to-datetime-conversion-converting-from-mm-dd-yyyy-object-value-type-to-d/43725038#comment74493635_43725014) in comment need pattern change by data - add `/` instead `-`:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format="%m/%d/%Y")
print (df)
  ID       date
0  A 2017-04-12
1  B 2017-04-27
2  C 2017-04-28
3  D 2017-04-29
4  E 2017-04-21
```

Comment: Very helpful! Thanks a lot jezrael

Comment: Glad can help you.